# Context Menu does not show again when launch an activity from

Tags: android

I have three tabs with set up three different activities.
When clicked on Tab3 its Activity is shown within the tabview.

```
    public class MyMovies extends Activity{
        private ViewFlipper mViewFlipper;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.my_movies_1);

            mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.my_movies);

            ... other code
            }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings.class));
            return true;
        }
    }
```

When I click on options menu it launches the Settings activity nicely. When I click back button then it goes back to this tab. However, subsequent options menu clicks no longer invokes onCreateOptionsMenu.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try catching `Menu` button clicks

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)
        {
            //populate the menu again
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Just in case:

Do you have these tags for Settings activity in your manifest

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE" />
```

Comment: Nikola thanks! Overriding onKeyUp does the trick. Since it did not make difference whether or not having two category tags for Settings in my manifest I did not place it. Still not sure why onCreateOptionsMenu is called but not called later. Tried to read and understand what android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE and SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE bu

Comment: onCreateOptionsMenu is somehow only to create it for the first time and only works when there is need for. In simple words.